# Android google maps PlacePicker getRating() returns -1

Tags: android, google-maps

I am using the PlacePicker from maps api to search for a place and get its rating. However, I am getting -1 for rating. I can see the actual rating value when I search for that place in google maps app. Other properties such as Name, position etc are fine as well.

```
@Override
  protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (requestCode == RESULT_CODE_SEARCH_PLACE) {
      Place place = PlacePicker.getPlace(this, data);
      float rating = place.getRating();
```

**Update 1:**
When I do a text search in PlacePicker, it returns me ratings like 3.59999, which is fine. But when I select the same place using the map in PlacePicker, it is returning -1.

Comment: The [documentation](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/places/Place.html#getRating()) states that *If no rating is known, a negative value is returned*. Maybe the rating hasn't been updated yet (it may take some time until the ratings propagate to all the Google services)

Comment: @antonio I am able to get rating by making api call to the endpoint /maps/api/place/details/json. However, when I try with the same place using PlacePicker, I am getting -1.

Comment: I created issue: https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=11343